# Apache poi library code for processing excel file doesn't work on jboss server

Tags: docker, jboss, apache-poi

I'm trying to parse an excel file on jboss which is inside a docker container

None of these approach work

```java
//1
new XSSFWorkbook();
//2
String filePath = "something";
File file = new File(filePath);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
Workbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
//3String filePath = "something";
File file = new File(filePath);
Workbook book = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
```

Also all of these fail without logging any error. I put all of these in a try block but in the logs the execution just stops when creating the workbook line. No logs appear after that and no code is run after that.
I've also tried `org.dhatim:fastexcel-reader` but the same thing happened with this.

I took the second approach from previous version production environment, it was working fine there.
Previously it was running on weblogic inside docker
Now it is running on jboss inside docker

Comment: What version of JBoss EAP or WildFly are you using?